# Why is OpenCV switching the shape when resizing?

Tags: opencv

Loading an image and then resizing it leads to the image being transposed:

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("example.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
print (image.shape)
print (cv2.resize(image, dsize=image.shape).shape)
```

With output:

```
(337, 458)
(458, 337)
```

Why do height and width change by using the resize operation? To be more precisely, why does the resize operator expect the dsize argument to be in the order of (width, height), while the shape attribute is in the order (height, width)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You told it to! Is the simple answer.

When you do:

```
print(image.shape)
```

it prints the `rows` and the `columns`, i.e. the height and the width.

When you resize it, you must tell it the new width and height, not the new height and the width.

Comment: Thanks, that is indeed true. Can you add an explanation, why this (apparent) inconsistency was chosen?

Comment: I *think* it's because `image.shape` is Python/NumPy thing and NumPy arrays are indexed by row first, then by column. That is called *"row major"* orderung. OpenCV comes at it from the other way and generally indexes by column first, probably because it has its origins in the C-programming world. I'll add any links I can find if I come across a better explanation - as can anyone else.